# Java to WSDL datatypes

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm doing some tests with Axis2 java2wsdl tool, creating little simple web services.

The first I created has a simple add method with two floats as input. The java2wsdl command created the WSDL document with no problem. Next I created another service with a method that returns a String array but I had problems with the WSDL datatypes that the tool generated:

java2wsdl generates :

```
`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"`/>
```

And with soapUI client I got the error: "Can't serialize type"

I modified it "by hand" to:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
```

And it worked.

The java source code is:

```
package Base;

public interface Base
{
 public String[] getNames();    
}
```

So, I don't understand why the tool did that mapping (String[] to xs:anyType)

Is there a special way that the java code must be written so java2esdl from axis2 creates the correct datatypes?

Thanks.

Comment: pls mention the command line you used for creating wsdl

Comment: Hi, this is the command:                                  $wsdl2java.sh -o . -ss -sd -ssi --noBuildXML --noWSDL -or -S ./src -R ./META-INF -uri WSDL_NAME.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

If you specify your type as xs:anyType  then you need to provide exact XSD type within the input message using xs:type attribute otherwise it's not possible to identify type of incoming message. This may helps to you http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-get-best-use-of-axis2-object.html